# Is it possible to override Symfony Intl JSON data?

Tags: symfony, intl

Is it possible to override json data under `symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Intl/Resources`?  For example, in `data/languages/en.json` I would like to change `"zh": "Chinese"` to be more specifically `"zh": "Mandarin Chinese"`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the pro with Symfony, but i get the same question and for me, i did find a workaround that works. I didn't use it in forms, i use it only to display.

I did create a Model called Country for accessing and manipulating the RegionBundle:

```
namespace AppBundle\Model;

use Symfony\Component\Intl\Data\Bundle\Reader\BufferedBundleReader;
use Symfony\Component\Intl\Data\Bundle\Reader\BundleEntryReader;
use Symfony\Component\Intl\Data\Bundle\Reader\JsonBundleReader;
use Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl;
use Symfony\Component\Intl\ResourceBundle\RegionBundle;


class Country
{

    public static function getCountryName($countryCode, $locale='de')
    {
        $test = new RegionBundle(
            __DIR__.'/../Resources/Intl/data'.'/'.Intl::REGION_DIR,
            new BundleEntryReader(new BufferedBundleReader(
                new JsonBundleReader(),
                Intl::BUFFER_SIZE
            )),
            Intl::getLocaleBundle()
        );

        return $test->getCountryName($countryCode, $locale);

    }

}
```

And from a controller, i can call them with:

```
Country::getCountryName('AF')
```

Maybe this is not the "state of the art" approach, but i was spending hours of searching another solution - but dont find any approach that is useable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to copy that file under **app/Resources/data/languages/en.json** than change it over there?

Also don't forget to clear cache

Comment: Tried both `app/Resources/data/languages/en.json` as well as `app/Resources/Intl/data/languages/en.json` but no joy.

Comment: Now try to copy in **src/YOURBUNDLE/Resources/data/languages/en.json**

Comment: Tried this as well.  No dice.

Comment: @nurikabe did you have any luck with that?

Comment: @PavelDubinin No, I eventually gave up.  Haven't revisited this issue.